# Yii CListView and conflict with MVC principles

Tags: php, yii

Yii masters!

We have a blog. Blog has a page with a list of authors. Authors are stored in AUTHOR table. I've used basic Yii-widget CListView to show it:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Author');
    $this->render('index', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

And than views/author/view.php:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_view',
));
```

But besides the information about author, this list must contain urls to five random related articles for each author. Article titles are stored in ARTICLE table. Now I use an ugly solution (views/authors/_view.php):

```
<ul class="experts-node-articles-list">
    <?php $authorArticles = Article::model()->findAllByAttributes(
        array('author_id' => $data->id), 
        array('limit' => '5'
    )); ?>
    <?php foreach ($authorArticles as $item) : ?>
    <li><a href="#"><?php echo CHtml::encode($item->title); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

It's ugly because of calling models in a view. It's a conflict with MVC-principles IMHO. Can I do this in true MVC way? I suspect it can be done through the model relations and scopes... But unfortunately I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create a Relation in **Author** model. (you can add/update `relations()` method like this)

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        .....
        'randomArticles' => array(
            self::HAS_MANY, 
            'Article', 
            'author_id',
            'limit' => 5,
            'order' => 'RAND()',
        ),
        .....
    );
}
```

2) Your dataprovider must be something like this.

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Author', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'with'=>array('randomArticles'),
    ),
));
```

3) And in your view (views/authors/_view.php), you can do something like this.

```
foreach($data->randomArticles as $article ) {
    // display $article info, something like below
    $this->renderPartial('_artical_info', array('article' => $article));
}
```

This saves lot of your sql queries.